# Django - postgreSQL - new connection is made for every page

Tags: django, postgresql, connection-pooling

**settings.py**

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'tutorial',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
        'CONN_MAX_AGE': 10,
    }
}
```

As I navigate to links in my website, a new connection is created. For example, upon entering <`domain.com`>, a new connection is created:

```
2018-08-10 06:22:15.301 CDT [3380] LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=56368
2018-08-10 06:22:15.306 CDT [3380] LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=tutorial
```

And upon navigating to one of the links, like <`domain.com/some_page/`>, another new connection is created.

```
2018-08-10 06:20:10.095 CDT [22932] LOG:  connection received: host=::1 port=56181
2018-08-10 06:20:10.098 CDT [22932] LOG:  connection authorized: user=postgres database=tutorial
```

When I have visited 10 different link within my domain and visit my 11th link, it finally reaches the maximum available connections, and disconnects the very first connection I established by visiting <`domain.com`>:

```
2018-08-10 06:30:17.715 CDT [6884] LOG:  disconnection: session time: 0:00:09.011 user=postgres database=tutorial host=::1 port=56368
```

Please note that `port=56368` was the exact same port I opened upon visiting my <`domain.com`> the first time. Apparently a new connection is established every time I visit a new link, and if the current number of connections exceeds the max connections, the very first connection is disconnected in order to accept a new connection.

But this is not I want. I don't want a new connection to be created every time a user visits a link inside my domain. I want to use only one connection throughout my entire domain per user. If a user opens a new tab, then I might want to establish a new connection, but not sure if this is the right way to do it.

How can I achieve this? Ideally I would want to use connection pooling, but I don't really know how to implement it inside Django. I know how to establish connection pooling system using a pure `psycopg2`, but not sure if I want to do it that way, since Django might support such functionality. Or should I just write separate `psycopg2` codes for connection pooling?

**Edit**

I'm aware that `CONN_MAX_AGE` specifies number of seconds that a request can be alive. But, the connection I used to load a page does not close after 10 seconds it was loaded. But instead, its behaving as if `CONN_MAX_AGE` is setting the maximum number of connections, and I do not know why. The log file outputs `disconnection:` message only if the number of connections exceeds `CONN_MAX_AGE`. IT DOES NOT outputs `disconnection` message after 10 seconds a page is loaded.

I'm using `Django 2.0.6`, `psycopg2 2.7.5`, `postgreSQL 10`

Comment: Well by setting `CONN_MAX_AGE` to 10, you let timeout a session every 10 seconds.

Comment: By default it is set to `None`, meaning connections will *never* expire.

Comment: Furthermore grouping connections per user is a bit strange. Django can handle a connection pool quite well, by adding such rules, the performance might drop.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think I lack understanding of how to implement connection pooling on Django. Is there any links you would recommend, for learning purposes?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and, when I set `CONN_MAX_AGE = 4`, the connection did not disconnect within 4 seconds after running. But instead, it seemed that when the connection reached 4, the first connection closed. That's what I observed from the log. Ik documentation says its in units of seconds, but from the logs, its not behaving like what documentation says

Comment: no typically it is closed upon actions (like a new request), the idea is that it is no longer used after 4 seconds.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem the connections didn't close when I visited a new link within my domain. When I visit a new link, isn't it sending a new request? Then the previous connection which was used to open the first link, should close after 4 seconds I visit the new link, but it didn't

Answer (score 0):

'CONN_MAX_AGE' is the number of seconds your connection keeps alive. Try removing that parameter from your db settings.

Django inherently does not support connection pooling. You can try take a connection from the pool and close a connection. But this is not actual connection pooling.